# Javascript - Adding A Permanent Placeholder onClick on Autocomplete Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, placeholder

Hopefully you can help on this javascript puzzle in my code. I m still learning javascript and jquery.  I admit I am a bit rusty and trying to get back into coding again. I have created a searchbox autocomplete.  I have created the javascript in my main html, and created an additional php page called autocomplete.php.  My auto complete is working but now I want to have is...  When a user click on one of the autocomplete choices below it will pop up the value which will then put an id in the search box for our system to search easier, but I also want to add a permanent place holder or text describing what they click on along with the id, but the text cannot be read by the search.  I just want to read the id.  In case, that is why I thought of a permanent placeholder.

On the PHP page I have created the onclick portion of the code:

```
<ul id="country-list" >
        <?php
        while($row=pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
        ?>  <li  onClick="selectCountry('<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>'); selectPlaceholder('<?php echo $row["country"].", ".$row["state"]; ?>');"> <?php echo "<strong>(".$row["id"].")</strong> ".$row["country"].", ".$row["state"]; ?> </li>
        <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

So I have created two type of onClicks which are selectCountry() and selectPlaceholder().

Here is my javascript code on the index page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#search-box").keyup(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/VCSWeb/wp-content/themes/i-excel-child/autocomplete.php",
    data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#suggesstion-box ").show();
        $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
        $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF");
    }
    });
});
});

function selectCountry(val) {
$("#search-box").val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}

function selectPlaceholder(val) {
$("placeholder").val("data-placeholder='"+val+"' ");    

}
```

As you can see at the bottom I am trying to turn the selectPlaceholder() into a variable and then pop it into my  tag to create something like data-placeholder='selectPlacehoder(value)'.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="frmSearch placeholder" style="width:90%; float:left;"   --->  data-placeholder='text'  <---(place javascript variable here)  >  
<label>                                             
    <input  size="59" maxlength="75" type="search" name="search"  class="search_keyword" id="search-box" placeholder="Enter Jurisdiction, County, City, or Client Name" />
    <div class="box" id="suggesstion-box"></div>

</label>                                            
</div>
```

Here is my CSS to make the placeholder permanent in the location

```
 .placeholder
{
   position: relative;
}

.placeholder::after
{
   position: absolute;
     left:150px;
   top: 10px;
   font-size:18px;
   content: attr(data-placeholder);
    pointer-events: none;
   opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Overall, need help with the javascripting turing the attribute into a variable, then taking the variable and poping it within a html div type tag.

```
function selectPlaceholder(val) {
$("placeholder").val("data-placeholder='"+val+"' ");   

}
```

So is this possible?  How can we do this? Do I need to create an id and then place it?  Would I need to put this in a .prop? Is there a better way?

Comment: Would https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js (Typeahead JS) work for you? Or is that not suitable for what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you want the user to see the text of the autocomplete option they selected, but you only want to send the row ID to the server.  I would consider not making the auto-complete search box the input that gets sent to the server.  Instead, I would create a hidden input with `name=[search]` and update that with the row ID to be sent to your server, then let the autocomplete input show the full description to the user.  This is more conventional, in my opinion.

So in the PHP auto complete rows:

```
<ul id="country-list" >
        <?php
        while($row=pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
        ?>  <li  onClick="selectCountry('<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>'); updateSearchBox(this);"> <?php echo "<strong>(".$row["id"].")</strong> ".$row["country"].", ".$row["state"]; ?> </li>
        <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function selectCountry(val) {
  $("#search-id").val(val);
  $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}

function updateSearchBox(el) {
  $("#search-box").val($(el).html());   
}
```

Main HTML:

```
<div class="frmSearch" style="width:90%; float:left;">  
<label>                                             
    <input  size="59" maxlength="75" type="search" class="search_keyword" id="search-box" placeholder="Enter Jurisdiction, County, City, or Client Name" />
    <input type="hidden" name="search" id="search-id"/>
    <div class="box" id="suggesstion-box"></div>

</label>                                            
</div>
```